GPS waypoint following
I am trying to create a node for Unitree go1 (4 legged robot)to follow gps waypoints. Can anyone guide me from scratch.

Quite a modest subject matter. Inital questions:


Which one of the Unitree Go1 models  do you have?


Do you already have a GPS sensor?


Assuming you're planning on using the navigation stack?



For ROS2 Compatibility I would start looking here, at the localization package - might help in giving you an understanding etc: https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/ros2/params/navsat_transform.yaml
